# How do you affect a DIV from an inner table's TD with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an outer DIV containing the content I want to block. However only the inner TD has the attributes as the qualifier.

I've already got the code (From an SO user) and use TamperMonkey to implement it and it works like a charm. However it removes too little and keeps the parent DIV. I know too little of JavaScript to affect the outter DIV.

```
<DIV>
   <Table></TABLE>
   <Table>
      <td attribute="desiredTarget"></td>
   </TABLE>
   <Table></TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Expected: DIV should not display based on TD content
Results: DIV still displays

Comment: Please show you attempts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I'm Limit has the answer below :)

Comment: Just because you got an answer doesn't mean your question was good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) it will better than PURE JS

```js
$('td[attribute="X"]')
  .parent() //TO TR
  .parent() //TO TBODY
  .parent() //TO TABLE
  .parent() //TO DIV
  .css("background-color", "red"); ///Your command
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Unnesscessary</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  2
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td attribute="X">xxx</td>
      <td>Unnesscessary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unnesscessary</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  3
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Unnesscessary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unnesscessary</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thankyouthankyouthankyou! This was the last thing I needed to make a custom troll blocker, thank you!

Comment: jQuery is absolutely unnecessary. This is trivially accomplished with vanilla JS.